# Its been 2 1/2 weeks and my node still hasnt synced. running on windows with Monero GUI wallet it has been stuck on last portion for majority

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, full-node

Its been 2 1/2 weeks and my node still hasnt synced. running on windows with Monero GUI wallet it has been stuck on last portion for majority. I have triple checked and opened ports 18080 intially on firewall and routers for in and out to allow all. I was then given an error in the log saying that I needed to open and bind my node to port 18081 after a crash. I forgot to change my router to allow in/out connections from 18080 to 18081. I did change my firewall on the windows device to allow 18081 in/out instead of 18080. This from what I have read might be my issue as it wasn't probably a good thing to do, without research and to find out why it was sating to do that first instead of hopping right into my settings and changing everything. as some reads that the 18081 port is used for rpc servers and public nodes. Well I am going to paste my monrod starting as of 1 hour ago and once again the estimated time to sync complete jumped from 2 days to now 26 days again. ALl my ports are changed back to 18080 and allowing in and out. Thats where the incoming connections are come from. all ips with ports of 18080.

2023-08-06 20:31:16.517 I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.2.2-release)
2023-08-06 20:31:16.517 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2023-08-06 20:31:16.517 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2023-08-06 20:31:16.518 I Initializing core...
2023-08-06 20:31:16.519 I Loading blockchain from folder C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb ...
2023-08-06 20:31:22.825 I Loading checkpoints
2023-08-06 20:31:22.826 I Core initialized OK
2023-08-06 20:31:22.827 I Initializing p2p server...
2023-08-06 20:31:22.876 I p2p server initialized OK
2023-08-06 20:31:22.876 I Initializing core RPC server...
2023-08-06 20:31:22.877 I Binding on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4):18081
2023-08-06 20:31:22.918 I core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
2023-08-06 20:31:22.944 I Starting core RPC server...
2023-08-06 20:31:22.946 I core RPC server started ok
2023-08-06 20:31:22.947 I Starting p2p net loop...
2023-08-06 20:31:23.961 I
2023-08-06 20:31:23.961 I **********************************************************************
2023-08-06 20:31:23.962 I The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. This may take a long time to complete.
2023-08-06 20:31:23.962 I
2023-08-06 20:31:23.962 I You can set the level of process detailization through "set_log <level|categories>" command,
2023-08-06 20:31:23.963 I where  is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING).
2023-08-06 20:31:23.963 I
2023-08-06 20:31:23.963 I Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
2023-08-06 20:31:23.963 I Use "help " to see a command's documentation.
2023-08-06 20:31:23.964 I **********************************************************************
2023-08-06 20:31:24.364 I [109.236.90.63:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2309769 -> 2946319 [Your node is 636550 blocks (2.4 years) behind]
2023-08-06 20:31:24.365 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2023-08-06 20:32:18.248 I Synced 2309789/2946321 (78%, 636532 left)
2023-08-06 20:33:30.308 I Synced 2309809/2946322 (78%, 636513 left, 0% of total synced, estimated 22.4 days left)
2023-08-06 20:35:04.594 I Synced 2309829/2946323 (78%, 636494 left)

As of the moment i am not sure how to get this to complete of if my monrod is even setup correctly

Comment: What kind of drive are you syncing the blockchain to?